# docx file is corrupted after download from server using php

Tags: php, download, docx, readfile

I'm trying to download a a word document (.docx) from the server using php. Unfortunately the document I get is corrupted. I can open the document with word, but I get these annoying messages (File is corrupted etc.). Here is my code:

```
$file = "documents/".$_POST["id_form"]."_document.docx";
$filename = $_POST["id_form"]."_document.docx";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);

readfile($file);
```

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

I got the solution. I had to put ***ob_end_clean()***; before the header and a ***exit;*** after readfile($file). Now it works fine.

Here is the working code:

```
    $file = "documents/".$_POST["id_form"]."_document.docx";
    $filename = $_POST["id_form"]."_document.docx";                 
    ob_end_clean();
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is not corrupted during the *upload* process? Can you verify that the file in question is not corrupt?

Comment: Are you echoing anything to the browser before or after? Do you have a closing `?>` in your script that might have a newline after it?

Comment: Yes, I tested that already. I can download the document with my ftp client and open it without getting these messages.

Comment: There's obviously a PHP error message or a full HTML document right in the middle of the stream. It should be obvious if you open it in a plain text editor.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. I can see some HTML code when I open the file with a regular text editor. How can I fix this?

Comment: could remove the html within the document with ob_clean()... but the file is still corrupted

Comment: Add HTML to remove it later? Why not just *not* add it?